# Is there a character in DC comics who has never died?

Tags: dc, comics

Superheroes in DC Comics die every now and then, but the superheroes usually come back to life (like superman) and the major villains also come back to life (like the Joker).

I would like to know if there is a DC superhero or supervillain that had never died at least once. Even if the hero or villain came back, if they died at a point in the continuity then they still died, and so that is not what I am looking for.

Off the top of my head, we can discount

- Superman. Was killed by Doomsday
- Batman. Killed by Darkseid.
- Wonder Woman. Killed by Neron
- Wally died multiple times, the Flash also died in Crisis on Infinite Earths
- Joker has died (in second appearance, Detective Comics 64, electrocuted)
- most if not all of the major icons

Is there any character in DC Comics that has not died in *any continuity*?

Edit: Death by any means counts. This includes death from old age, illness, and trauma.

Comment: so are you asking they have never died ever in any continuity or never in one single continuity? because the former will be very hard to find

Comment: @Braden Phirsichbaum - Does dying of old age count? If so, I believe every human character on present day Earth was dead by the 30th century, in which the Legion of Super-Heroes formed.

Comment: Shazam does come to mind, dont remember him dying ever!

Comment: https://screenrant.com/superheroes-never-died-comics/ or  https://www.cbr.com/dc-characters-never-died/ might be helpful for an answer

Comment: In _Superman/Doomsday: Hunter/Prey_, Superman time-travelled to a point in the "far distant future" described as "the end of time." At that point, the universe was being crushed by entropy, and even beings like Superman and Doomsday couldn't survive there for long. Presumably, pretty much every mortal character ever shown in a DC story was dead in that time period.

Comment: @Braden Phirsichbaum - I doubt the "end of time" was literally the last nanosecond of reality, because Superman and Waverider were there long enough to talk a little bit, and then leave. Also, when the main DC universe was rebooted in the _Zero Hour_ storyline, the events of _Hunter/Prey_ happened again, but this time, some other time-travellers arrived just in time to prevent Doomsday from being crushed by entropy and bring him back to present day Earth.

Comment: Considering the fact that the timeline stretches to ["the end of time"](https://www.dc.com/blog/2021/02/18/bright-or-bleak-ranking-the-dc-universes-possible-futures), only immortal beings are even possibilities.

Comment: Doctor Fate cannot die. Only the one wearing the helmet dies.

Comment: @shanu He dies in the Injustice story line.

Comment: [The Presence](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Presence) perhaps?

Comment: Does "in any continuity" include what-if / one-off kind of stories? For example, does Captain Marvel's death in Frank Miller's *Dark Knight Strikes Again* (not ever intended to be part of the "main" continuity, though in continuity with Miller's little bubble of Batman comics) count? Would various character deaths in Alan Moore's (explicitly non-canon "imaginary story") *Whatever Happened to the Man of Tomorrow* count?

Comment: @Clockwork Constantine kills Doctor Fate (as the presence inside the helmet). Fate is then replaced by another being.

Comment: Does the Vertigo count as part of DC? Most of Fables are immortal, even if they can temporary "die.  There are those that are either never "died" at all (like Snow White) or are so powerful, that come back immediately to life (Jack of the Beanstalk)

Comment: @evilsoup Asker deleted their own account after self-answering, but I think _any_ kind of death in any occurrence would have counted, apparently.

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on your definitions, and what you count as dying.

Death of the Endless survived until the very end of the Universe. ([The Books of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Books_of_Magic))

However, for one day every hundred years, she incarnated as a mortal. Her mortal body died.

Does she count?

[image]

Comment: This was my first thought also, but she's neither a supervillain nor a superhero...

Answer (score 1):

### The Presence/Voice/Source/Hand

I think I have an answer, but I'm not 100% sure. In the comments, some characters given were Dr. Fate (in the Helmet), The Presence, and Shazam. Assuming Dr. Fate is based in the Helmet, the Helmet was melted and turned into a dagger by Jared Stevens. Shazam died in Ground Zero #20, part of the Injustice storylines. The Presence seemed to be killed by Gabriel, *however,* the Presence later reveals that Gabriel only killed a part, or aspect to the Presence. The Presence include the Hand, the Voice, and the Source. Therefore, the Presence did not completely die.

Many thanks goes to @shanu for the suggestion of Shazam, @Laurel for noting that a survivor would be immortal, and especially @clockwork for suggesting the Presence. When @clockwork mentioned the Presence, then I remembered that TOAA and The Presence were both Omnipotent characters, and were thus immortal. Hence, the deduction is that The Presence in DC has never died, because he cannot die, being Omnipotent.

Answer (score 1):

**VANDAL SAVAGE**

[image]

[Vandal Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandal_Savage) was born 50,000 years ago and gained immortality after exposure to the radiation of a strange meteorite (later retconned to be a colony of sub-atomic robots called "tektites" inhabiting his bloodstream and cells).

In the original Golden Age and Silver Age stories, Vandal Savage was ageless but could still die by injury. Starting in the 1980s, Savage was depicted not only as ageless but also having superhuman healing abilities, meaning his body could repair itself from lethal damage and destruction.

From what I can find, Savage has never died in any of the canon comics timelines, but in the crossover storyline *DC One Million*, a version of Vandal Savage was alive in a possible version of the 853rd century. This version of Savage was later permanently killed by a nuclear explosion; but this, however, is only one possible future for Savage.

In the TV "Arrowerse". though, [Vandal Savage is killed twice](https://www.cbr.com/who-is-vandal-savage/). He is resurrected the first time and goes to hell the second time (and enjoys being there). However, as the question specifically asks about comics, these deaths don't count.

Comment: He also died in the alternate DCeased universe, ripped in half by an unliving Wonder Woman. Since asker wanted a character that never died in any continuity, I think it doesn't work. But nice to know.